# Sending razor variable as function parameter on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress-mvc

I read many posts about sending razor variables to javascript as funtion parameters, but nothing worked for me.

Here is my razor view:

```
string uniqueIdFirst = Model.Requests.FirstOrDefault().UniqueId;
@Html.DevExpress().Button( saveSett =>
{
    saveSett.Name = "btnCancelRequest";
    saveSett.Text = "Cancel";
    saveSett.Width = 63;
    saveSett.Height = 28;
    saveSett.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
    saveSett.Styles.EnableDefaultAppearance = false;
    saveSett.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
    saveSett.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e) { BtnCancelRequest('@uniqueIdFirst'); }";
} ).GetHtml();
```

When I debug javascript function BtnCancelRequest I see that I get just string "@uniqueIdFirst".

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a js variable for that, try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uniqueIdFirst = '@Model.Requests.FirstOrDefault().UniqueId';
</script>
```

and in event :

```
saveSett.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e) { BtnCancelRequest(uniqueIdFirst); }";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use external JS files, better way to create:

```
@{
    string uniqueIdFirst = Model.Requests.FirstOrDefault().UniqueId;
}

saveSett.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e) {BtnCancelRequest('" + uniqueIdFirst + "'); }";
```